# Separate div tags append together in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html

The web page I need help with is at http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/.bio/

My problem is, as you will be able to see in the source code, I have 2 `div`s on my page:
*(Note the "hu" and "en" attrrubutes, they're used by JS)*

```
<div hu>
    - content -
    <table>
        <tr><td>- stuff -</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" en>
    - content -
    <table>
        <tr><td>- stuff -</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the JS I use inc. jQuery:

```
//readCookie() is a different function for reading a cookie that was set before. 

if (readCookie('lang') == "en"){
    $('*[hu]').hide()
    $('*[en]').show()
}
```

Accordingly, if the `lang` cookie is set with the value of `en`, it will hide anything that has the `hu` attribute, and will show anything that has the `en` attribute.

The problem comes in when I check **how Google Chrome loads** the page content:
*(The second `div` gets appended to the first one, and when the first one gets hidden, the second won't show either)*

```
<div style="display:none;" hu>
    - content -
    <table>
        <tr><td>- stuff -</td></tr>
    </table>

    <div en>
        - content -
        <table>
            <tr><td>- stuff -</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the first div to `span`, same with the second, but neither solved the merging issue. I'm guessing this has to do something with the tables since other parts of the page is not affected by this problem.

So, how can I fix this?

Note: On the page, you can use the JS console to set cookies, just use createCookie('lang',['en'|'hu'],2)

Comment: There are no such attributes like `hu` or `en` in HTML. Use either `lang="hu"` (only if the text content is in Hungarian) or `data-lang="hu"` to store that information.

Comment: agreed, also add a proper `doctype` to the page. fix those issues and see where that gets you.

Comment: @MattK Done it, still nothing.

Comment: @feeela I know they don't exist, I just used them. Also adding the data-lang="hu" and "en" didn't solve the problem of the 2 divs appending to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not closed the `table`-tags in your HTML source – but you have posted it above without errors. Next time please paste the code from your page into a question…

view-source:http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/.bio/

```
<table>
    <!-- … ->
<table>
<div id="contact">
```

Comment: Oh wow, really. Now I feel stupid :(
Closing the tags worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @DJDavid98 You are also using IDs twice, which is illegal in HTML and could lead to further problems when scripting or styling the page. For example `<div id="contact">` exists twice. You should read a basic HTML tutorial.

Comment: That's just a leftover from a code change which I've just done, I'll clean it up right now. Thanks for the heads up tho.